# no kind "APIService" is registered error when running `linkerd upgrade --from-manifests`

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

When running `linkerd upgrade --from-manifests` the following error occurs:

```
linkerd upgrade --from-manifests install.yaml > install-new.yaml
× Failed to parse Kubernetes objects from manifest install.yaml: no kind "APIService" is registered for version "apiregistration.k8s.io/v1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:101"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/3559) with a workaround.

The workaround is to export the `secret/linkerd-identity-issuer` and `configmap/linkerd-config` resources to a separate manifest file, then use the generated file as an argument to `linkerd upgrade --from-manifests`:

```
kubectl -n linkerd get \
  secret/linkerd-identity-issuer \
  configmap/linkerd-config \
  -oyaml > linkerd-manifests.yaml
```

then:

`linkerd upgrade --from-manifests linkerd-manifests.yaml`